# open new terminal in the same work directory

Tags: bash

Here is the problem:

I am working on my virtual machine `computer A`, and from this machine I do an ssh to another computer `computer B`, in which I am working.

In the `.bashrc` of `computer A`, I have an ssh instruction thanks to which I can automatically connect to computer B.

When working in the path `~/dir1/dir2` of `computer B`, I would like to open a new terminal and keep working in the path `~/dir1/dir2` (i.e. avoiding therefore the start in ~).

I have tried to expand the `.bashrc` of `computer B` with the [following reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32508/how-can-i-open-a-new-terminal-in-the-same-directory-of-the-last-used-one-from-a) , but it is not working.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You would need that answer's stuff set on computer B for it to work there not on computer A. What does the auto-ssh bit of your `.bashrc` file look like for the record?

Comment: Thanks. I will keep on thinking about how to do it. For the ssh I just put     exec               ssh -X username@addressmachine

Comment: So you never use computer A for anything real then? The trick in that linked ticket is that it keeps the "current" directory in a file that new shells read so they can change to that directory also. That requires being done on the machine you are operating on. So you need that on computer B (not computer A).